# Integer.parseInt() lanza java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java

En este ejercicio tengo que introducir una cadena con cuatro números separados por un espacio, mandarlo al servidor, luego el servidor sumará el primero más el segundo, luego multiplicarlo por el tercero y finalmente restarle el cuarto. El resultado lo mandará de vuelta al cliente. De nuevo el cliente mandará otros cuatro números. El proceso se repetirá hasta que el cliente mande un *, en ese caso el servidor se cierra (mandando una "x" como respuesta para que el cliente también se cierre). Hay que hacerlo utilizando UDP.

Pues el problema es que le mando una cadena al servidor, luego este la transforma en array con método split, y luego para poder operar con estos números tengo que pasarlos a int, con Integer.parseInt(). Y ahí es donde viene el problema, que me da un error con la excepción NumberFormatException.

Código cliente:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String cadena;      
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                       
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();

        byte[] listData = new byte[1024];       
        byte[] datosEnviados = new byte[1024];
        byte[] datosRecibidos = new byte[1024];


        InetAddress IPServidor = InetAddress.getByName(//aquí pondre mi dirección IP); 
        int puerto = 6000;        


        while(true) {

            System.out.println("Introduce 4 números separados por un espacio en blanco: ");
            cadena = in.readLine();


            listData = cadena.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket envio = new DatagramPacket(listData, listData.length, IPServidor, puerto);
            clientSocket.send(envio);           

            //recibimos respuesta del servidor
            DatagramPacket recibo = new DatagramPacket(datosRecibidos, datosRecibidos.length);
            System.out.println("Esperando datagrama...");
            clientSocket.receive(recibo);
            String numero = new String(recibo.getData());                        
            if (numero.equals("x")) {
                break;           
            }        
            System.out.println("\t Datos: " + numero);      

        } //Fin While

        clientSocket.close(); //Cerramos cliente
    }

}
```

Código servidor:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(6000);
        byte[] infoRecibida = new byte[1024];
        byte[] infoEnviada = new byte[1024];
        byte[] paquete = new byte[1024];
        String cadena;
        List list;
        int n1,n2,n3,n4;
        int res;
        String num;
        String num1,num2,num3,num4;
        String x;


        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Esperando datagrama...");            
            infoRecibida = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket paqRecibido = new DatagramPacket(infoRecibida, infoRecibida.length);
            serverSocket.receive(paqRecibido);     
            cadena = new String(paqRecibido.getData());

         // IP y puerto desde donde se manda mensaje
            InetAddress IPOrigen = paqRecibido.getAddress();
            int puerto = paqRecibido.getPort();


            String[] numeros = cadena.split(" ");
            n1 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[0]);
            n2 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[1]);
            n3 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[2]);
            n4 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[3]);

            num1= Integer.toString(n1);
            num2= Integer.toString(n2);
            num3= Integer.toString(n3);
            num4= Integer.toString(n4);

            // Si alguno de los números introducidos es * 
            // envío "x" al cliente para que este se cierre, posteriormente sale del bucle y se cierra también el servidor
            if (num1=="*"||num2=="*"||num3=="*"||num4=="*") {
                x = "x";
                paquete = x.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket paqueteFinal = new DatagramPacket(paquete, paquete.length, IPOrigen, puerto);
                break;
            }

            //Hago las operaciones, el resultado lo paso a cadena y luego a bytes, para ser enviado al cliente
            res=(n1+n2)*n3-n4;
            num = Integer.toString(res);                      
            infoEnviada=num.getBytes();


            // ENVIO DATAGRAMA AL CLIENTE
            DatagramPacket paqEnviado = new DatagramPacket(infoEnviada, infoEnviada.length, IPOrigen, puerto);
            serverSocket.send(paqEnviado);

        } //Fin While


        serverSocket.close();
        System.out.println("Socket cerrado...");

    }

}
```

El error que me marca es

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Servidor.main(Servidor.java:43)
```

Comment: Deberías comprobar si lo que te llega es una "x" antes de hacer el parseInt. Debes asegurarte siempre que lo que le llega a esta función es un numero en string, como por ejemplo "12". En el momento que tenga algún espacio o un carácter no numérico te dará error. Por otro lado te recomendaría usar otro delimitador que no sea espacio.

Comment: yo creo que el error es bastante descriptivo de lo que te está pasando... 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4
estás intentando convertir a número algo que no es un número, debuguea tu código hasta la línea que falla y mira a ver lo que le está llegando al parseInt, te recomiendo que intentes resolver estas cosas tu solo porque es así como vas a aprender las bases del desarrollo

Comment: La verdad es que soy un poco novato aún en el mundillo de la programación. Pero que yo sepa String[] numeros es un array formado por elementos de tipo String... hasta ahí llego. Y que yo sepa una cadena o String se puede convertir a int con Integer.parseInt(nombreCadena). Lo que me llama la atención es que en el aviso que me lanza el 4 sólo lleva las comillas de apertura, no deberían estar las de cierre también?

Comment: El problema te viene cuando intentas convertir `*` en un int. El asterisco no es ningun entero y por eso te da un pete de parseo. Deberias de añadir antes del parseInt un condicional de si `numeros[0].equals("*")`, entonces no hace el resto de codigo

Comment: Como bien te comentan tienes varios fallos de diseño. Tanto en el cliente como en el servidor. Lo primero que debes hacer antes de intentar usar `parseInt()` es debuguear la *cadena* que recibes. Un simple `System.out.println(cadena);` te dará una pista de lo que estás recibiendo. Por otro lado, piensa esto: Si haces que `n1` o cualquiera de ellos sea un valor entero, ¿Crees que `if (num1=="*")...` tenga sentido? Los números enteros no incluyen el carácter `*`. Asi que, como te recomienda @Blazerg, a ensuciarse un poco más las manos y programar. Saludos

Comment: Pues la verdad tendré que mirarlo mejor porque no termino de entender lo que me estáis diciendo. n1 lo convierto en int, pero num1 lo he convertido previamente en String con el método Integer.toString(n1), no es cierto? Que yo sepa puedo poner (if num1 == "*") porque previamente num1 ya lo he transformado en cadena. Pero bueno no seré yo el novato quien os lleve la contraria a vosotros que seguro estáis más curtidos que yo, está claro que quien  ha fallado he sido yo y ahora mismo no soy capaz de verlo. Pero seguiré intentando a ver...

Comment: No te sientas mal con los comentarios, tratamos de ayudarte. Tu mismo trata de razonar esto, dices: ***n1 lo convierto en int***, muy bien, ¿qué posibles valores puede tener *n1*? Cualquier valor numérico entero. Luego dices: ***num1 lo he convertido previamente en String***, perfecto, y ¿qué valores puede tener ahora *num1*? Pues un `string` que representa un valor entero, por lo tanto nunca puede ser un asterisco (`*`). Es eso lo que trato de que logres entender. Son esos sutiles detalles los que nos ayudan a mejorar nuestro código y la forma en la que programamos. Saludos

Comment: También ten en cuenta que en java no puedes comparar Strings usando el comparador == que sirve para comparar posiciones de memoria y no el contenido, para ello debes usar el método equals, por ejemplo num4.equals("*"). Tienes múltiples fallos básicos, por eso te comentamos que repases lo básico e intentes ensuciarte con el código antes de preguntar por aquí porque si te damos las respuestas no vas a ganar las bases que necesitas, espero que no te moleste el comentario que es con toda la buena intención del mundo, saludos!!!!!!

Comment: A mí no me molestan los comentarios para nada, pues sé que son para ayudar y soy consciente que en esta profesión uno tiene que aprender a batallar con el código e intentar valerse por sí mismo, cuanto menos dependiente seas mucho mejor, tenéis toda la razón. Por ejemplo yo pensaba que daba lo mismo usar == que .equals(), ya veo que no, gracias también por el aporte, y al final resulta que me daba fallo porque tenía que poner el método trim() para cada elemento del array, cosa que yo no hice Al menos ahora si devuelve el resultado de las operaciones con los numeros.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no los estas tratando como array para convertirlos. Una posible solución podría ser la siguiente:

```
String[] numeros = cadena.split(" ");

for(i = 0; i < numeros .length; i++) {
   String nValor= numeros[i].trim();
   int value = Integer.parseInt(nValor);

}
```

En caso que que estes utilizando `Java 8`, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
    String[] numeros = cadena.split(" ");

    for (i = 0; i < numeros .length; i++){
        Integer.parseInt(numeros [i])

    }
```

Esta parte la tienes que modificar en el servicio

Comment: No había puesto el método trim() a los elementos de mi array y por eso me daba error al utilizar el parseInt(). Ahora ya puedo meter numeros y operar con ellos, aunque ahora el fallo lo tengo con el asterisco que no se me cierra el servidor al leerlo. Pero bueno, al menos he avanzado. Gracias por la aportación.

Answer (score 0):

Adjunto el código correcto. Como podéis observar es casi igual que el código anterior, sólo que en la clase Servidor a cada elemento del array le agregue el método .trim(), y después de eso ya puedes parsearlo a entero sin que de error. Y luego el if lo cambié de sitio colocándolo justo antes de convertir los elementos del array a tipo int.

Gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda y consejos.

Clase Cliente:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String cadena;      
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));                       
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();

        byte[] listData = new byte[1024];       
        byte[] datosEnviados = new byte[1024];
        byte[] datosRecibidos = new byte[1024];


        InetAddress IPServidor = InetAddress.getByName("//aquí se pone numero de ip del servidor"); 
        int puerto = 6000;        


        while(true) {

            System.out.println("Introduce 4 números separados por un espacio en blanco: ");
            cadena = in.readLine();


            listData = cadena.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket envio = new DatagramPacket(listData, listData.length, IPServidor, puerto);
            clientSocket.send(envio);           

            //recibimos respuesta del servidor
            DatagramPacket recibo = new DatagramPacket(datosRecibidos, datosRecibidos.length);
            System.out.println("Esperando datagrama...");
            clientSocket.receive(recibo);
            String numero = new String(recibo.getData());                        
            if (numero.equals("x")) {
                break;           
            }        
            System.out.println("\t Datos: " + numero);      

        } //Fin While

        clientSocket.close(); //Cerramos cliente
    }

}
```

Clase Servidor:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(6000);
        byte[] infoRecibida = new byte[1024];
        byte[] infoEnviada = new byte[1024];
        byte[] paquete = new byte[1024];
        String cadena;
        List list;
        int n1,n2,n3,n4;
        int res;
        String num;
        String num1,num2,num3,num4;
        String x;


        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Esperando datagrama...");            
            infoRecibida = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket paqRecibido = new DatagramPacket(infoRecibida, infoRecibida.length);
            serverSocket.receive(paqRecibido);     
            cadena = new String(paqRecibido.getData());

         // IP y puerto desde donde se manda mensaje
            InetAddress IPOrigen = paqRecibido.getAddress();
            int puerto = paqRecibido.getPort();


            String[] numeros = cadena.split(" ");

         // Si alguno de los números introducidos es * 
            // envío "x" al cliente para que este se cierre, posteriormente sale del bucle y se cierra también el servidor

            if (numeros[0].equals("*")||numeros[1].equals("*")||numeros[2].equals("*")||numeros[3].equals("*")) {
                x = "x";
                paquete = x.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket paqueteFinal = new DatagramPacket(paquete, paquete.length, IPOrigen, puerto);
                break;
            }


            n1 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[0].trim());
            n2 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[1].trim());
            n3 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[2].trim());
            n4 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[3].trim());


            //Hago las operaciones, el resultado lo paso a cadena y luego a bytes, para ser enviado al cliente
            res=(n1+n2)*n3-n4;
            num = Integer.toString(res);                      
            infoEnviada=num.getBytes();


            // ENVIO DATAGRAMA AL CLIENTE
            DatagramPacket paqEnviado = new DatagramPacket(infoEnviada, infoEnviada.length, IPOrigen, puerto);
            serverSocket.send(paqEnviado);

        } //Fin While


        serverSocket.close();
        System.out.println("Socket cerrado...");

    }

}
```